# Apply a raw parameter from one data frame to another using plyr package

Tags: r, file, plyr

I want to take the following index data frame:

```
sample   label                            Path
1       B6_01      B6   zap17KO_data/B6_1_May2015.tsv
2       B6_02      B6   zap17KO_data/B6_2_May2015.tsv
3       B6_03      B6   zap17KO_data/B6_3_May2015.tsv
4     Quad_01    Quad zap17KO_data/Quad_1_May2015.tsv
5     Quad_02    Quad zap17KO_data/Quad_2_May2015.tsv
6     Quad_03    Quad zap17KO_data/Quad_3_May2015.tsv
7  ZAPKODN_01 ZAPKODN      zap17KO_data/ZAPKODN_1.tsv
8  ZAPKODP_01 ZAPKODP      zap17KO_data/ZAPKODP_1.tsv
9  ZAPKODP_02 ZAPKODP      zap17KO_data/ZAPKODP_2.tsv
10 ZAPKODP_03 ZAPKODP      zap17KO_data/ZAPKODP_3.tsv
```

And to read each of the files in the paths to a single data frame and that for each raw of the new data frame I will have the concordant sample and label.

I tried to do it by reading the index data frame to a list:

```
flist <- index$paths
names(flist) <- index$sample
db <- ldply(flist, read.delim)
```

The problem here is that I don't have the label for each raw in the db data frame and I need to use "match" function to get it right from which I want to abstain.

Comment: Do you want to read those files in each ROW in 1 dataframe or multiple?

Comment: @maxPD one data frame

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
res <- 
  do.call(rbind,
          lapply(1:nrow(index),function(i){
            myPath <- index[i, "Path"]
            mySample <- index[i, "sample"]
            myLabel <- index[i, "label"]

            #read tsv
            d <- read.table(myPath, sep = "\t")

            #result
            cbind(mySample, myLable, d)
          }
          ))
```

Answer (score 0):

As I was looking for a solution with the plyr package i found this to work:

```
db <- ddply(index, .(Path), function(x){
  df <- read.delim (x$Path)
  df$.id <- x$sample
  df$label <- x$label
  return(df)
})
```